# selector find parent sibling(img_wrap img)

Tags: jquery

below code try to make if btn mousedown find parent siblings(img_wp) img, but it doesn't work. my code wrong in somewhere?

```
$('.btn').mousedown(function(e){
    var target_img = $(e.target).parent().closest('.img_wp img');
    var target_img_w = target_img.width();
    var target_img_h = target_img.height();
    console.log(target_img_w + target_img_h);
});

<div class=\"wp\">
    <div class="img_wp">
        <img>
    </div>
    <div class="btn_wp">
        <div class="btn"></div>
    </div>
</div>
 <div class=\"wp\">
    <div class="img_wp">
        <img>
    </div>
    <div class="btn_wp">
        <div class="btn"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.closest()` looks for the closest ancestor with a matching selector. Since your button's parent has no `img` ancestor, your selector returns an empty set.

---

Use this instead:

```
var target_img = $(this).closest('.wp').find('img');
```